# User specific default database in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive

I am running a Oracle Big Data Appliance platform that has Cloudera EDH 5.9.x running under the hood. My users are mainly using beeswax, which is the Hive query editor app within Hue.

When a user logs into Hue and then opens beeswax, the default Hive database "default" is preselected. I want to change this so that the first database they see is their own sandbox database. Currently, the user has to manually select the database from beeswax or run the `use DATABASE` command in the editor.

Is there a configuration item I can change within any of the CDH software modules that will help me do this? Or is there a concept of a Hive startup script where I can run the `use DATABASE` command?

Answer (score 1):

In bypass mode Hive clients directly access the metastore database instead of using the Hive Metastore Server for metastore information.

1. Go to the Hive service.
2. Click the Configuration tab.
3. Select Scope > HIVE service_name (Service-Wide)
4. Select Category > Advanced.
5. Deselect the Bypass Hive Metastore Server property.
6. Click Save Changes to commit the changes.
7. Re-deploy Hive client configurations.
8. Restart Hive and any Hue or Impala services configured to use that Hive service.

This might work for you.